# user defined function in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

This piece of code is working fine with normal php:

```
<?php
function barber($type)
{
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem\n";
}
call_user_func('barber', "mushroom");
call_user_func('barber', "shave");
?>
```

How do i implement the same stuff with in an Action of a Zend controller ? (I believe Zend wont allow to call a function with in quotes and **$this** and **self** are not possible in this matter)

Comment: How do i execute call_user_func('barber', "mushroom"); with in an Action of a controller in zend ?

Comment: The first argument 'barber' is not taking as a function in zend framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method in your controller, eg

```
private function foo($var) {
    return $var++;
}
```

Call it like this using `call_user_func()`

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'foo'), $a);
```

Comment: Ok fine it worked !! im passing the value of $a as 1 so normally i want to get the result as 2..but still the result is 1